# Linq to XML and reading XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have a web service which i believe is raw XML (by that i mean the URL to the service is         [http://site/service]). If i was to pass in a value [http://site/service/?value=test] then i see a list of XML nodes.

What i would like to do is see examples (or an explanation) of how i could use this page with Linq to XML as the backend - most of the examples i have seen dont seem related or i may not have understood it correctly.

In addition what i would like to do is have the backend (Linq to XML) to be a DAL where i could pass in values from the UI.

Is this how i should go about it if so could someone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to provide the url to the `XDocument.Load()` static method to load the document. Then you should be able to query or change the document. If you want to save modified document you would use the `XDocument.Save()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to provide the url to the XDocument.Load() static method to load the document. Then you should be able to query or change the document. If you want to save modified document you would use the XDocument.Save() method.